# Prevent inserting duplicate elements - instead routing to existing element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This is how I'm adding some elements to a list (which consists of links to articles) via an input field:

```
Template.addForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var title = event.target.text.value;    
        MongoValues.insert({
            title: title,
            slug: title.toLowerCase()
        }, function(error, result) { if(error) console.warn(error); });
        event.target.text.value = "";
    }
});
```

Now I want to prevent double entries: If the user wants to add an already existing title he should be routed to this already existing element (route to `article/_id`), instead of adding the title to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using iron:router and have a route like this :

```
Router.route('article/:_id', {
    name: 'article'
    // other route stuff
});
```

You could adjust your code as follows:

```
Template.addForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var title = event.target.text.value; 
        var existing = MongoValues.findOne({title : title});
        if (!!existing) { 
          // title already exists, go to article page
          Router.go("article", {_id : existing._id});
        } else {   
          // title doesnt exist, so go ahead and insert
          MongoValues.insert({
              title: title,
              slug: title.toLowerCase()
          }, function(error, result) { 
            if(error) {
              console.warn(error); 
            }
          });
          event.target.text.value = "";
      }
    }
  });
```

Note that this will not prevent duplicates if the user bypasses this code (i.e. by doing the insert from the console).

If you are using Collection2 and SimpleSchema, you can set a unique constraint on the title field to ensure that only unique values ever get inserted, regardless of where the insert happens. To do this, just specify "unique: true" in your field definition, like so:

```
title : {
   type: String,
   unique: true
}
```

Comment: Could you please post an example, as I'm using Collection2 and SimpleSchema?

Comment: Why do you do `!!existing` instead of `existing`? The colon at the end of the findOne-line should be a semicolon.

Comment: added a brief example.  as to your second question, force of habit and unnecessary in this instance, but does the same things as just "existing"